# Error running application in flutter - NEHotspotNetwork

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, onesignal

I have an application developed in flutter. After updating xcode to version 15.2 and IOS 17.2, I am getting this error:

> container_create_or_lookup_app_group_path_by_app_group_identifier: client is not entitled
> Blockquote

I also have this image with the error that appears in the console.

[image]

This leaves the application loading.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me?